# Constructing regular expressions for languages

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm new to regular expressions and I'm currently working on some exercises to get familiar in constructing regular expressions for languages. 
I have the following languages, for which I already tried to write the corresponding regular expressions.

Could you please tell me if they are correct or what I could improve? I would really appreciate your help.

$L_1 = \{w \in \{a, b\}^* : |w| \text{ is divisible by 3}\}$
$r_1=((a+b)(a+b)(a+b))^*$

$L_2 = \{w \in \{a, b\}^* : w \text{ contains } aa \text{ or } bb\}$
$r_2=(a+b)^*aa(a+b)^*+(a+b)^*bb(a+b)^*$

$L_3 = \{w \in \{a, b\}^* : w \text{ contains } aa \text{ and } bb\}$
$r_3=(a+b)^*aa(a+b)^*bb(a+b)^*$

$L_4 = \{w \in \{a, b\}^* : w \text{ contains } ab \text{ and } ba\}$
$r_4=(a+b)^*ab(a+b)^*ba(a+b)^*+(a+b)^*ba(a+b)^*ab(a+b)^*$

$L_5 = \{w \in \{a, b\}^* : |w|_a \le 1 \text{ or } |w|_b \ge 2\}$
$r_5=(b^*+b^*ab^*)+a^*bbb^*a^*$

$L_6 = \{w \in \{a, b\}^* : |w|_a \le 1 \text{ and } |w|_b \ge 1\}$
$r_6=(b*+b*ab^*)(a*bb^*a^*)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r_1$ and $r_2$ are correct, also I'd write $r_2$ shorter as $(a+b)^*(aa+bb)(a+b)^*$.

$r_3$ is wrong, note that $bbaa \in L_3$ isn't matched by $r_3$, $r_3$ matches the words which contain $aa$ before $bb$, you can fix this by writing 
$$ (a+b)^*\bigl(aa(a+b)^*bb + bb(a+b)^*aa\bigr) (a+b)^* $$
that is, just adding the other case.

$r_4$ is correct, here you got the point you were missing in $r_3$.

If $|w|_a$ denotes the number of $a$s (and the same for $b$'s), $r_5$ is wrong. The $a$-part is correct, but at least two $b$'s is $a^*ba^*b(a+b)^*$ (note that the $b$'s do not need to be connected), so we have 
$$ (b^* + b^*ab^*) + a^*ba^*b(a+b)^* $$

$r_6$ is also wrong, note that each of you $a^*$ can give as many $a$'s as we want, even more than one. $L_6$ consists of two types of words, those with no $a$ (given by the RE $bb^*$ [we need at least one $b$]) and those with one $a$, given by $b^*(ab+ba)b^*$ (note that we need one $b$), hence 
$$ r_6 = bb^* + b^*(ab+ba)b^* $$

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helped me a lot to understand my wrong reasoning. I got it now.